# How to insert data into database using prepared statement query in Django and Python

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I need to insert form data into SQLite3 database using prepared statement query in Django and Python. My code is below:

models.py:

```
class Meeting(models.Model):
    """In this class the columns for Meeting table has declared"""
    room_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    from_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    to_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    no_seat = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    projector = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    video = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
```

Here I have already created the table by migrating. My `views.py` is below:

```
import sqlite3
def insert(request):

    """ This function helps to insert all booking data into database """
    conn = sqlite3.connect("db.sqlite3")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        location_name = request.POST.get('lname')
        rname = request.POST.get('rname')
        seat = request.POST.get('seat')
        projector = request.POST.get('projector')
        video = request.POST.get('video')
        location_name = location_name[0:255]
        rname = rname[0:255]
        seat = seat[0:10]
        from_date = request.POST.get('from_date')
        to_date = request.POST.get('from_date')
```

Here I need all data should save into the database by running prepared statement query.

Comment: Is this for an assignment or something? Why do you need to use prepared statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's SQLite libraries don't have prepared statement objects, but they do allow you to use parameterized queries, and to provide more than one set of parameters.

```
values_to_insert = [(location_name,rname,........other_fields)]

cursor.execute("""
    INSERT INTO some_table ('location_name', 'rname','..... other_fields')
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, total fields = total ? marks)""", values_to_insert)
```

Comment: I am doing like this `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO booking_meeting VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (None, rname, from_date, to_date, seat, projector, video, now, location_name))` but here i am getting this `Exception Value: 
local variable 'location_name' referenced before assignment` error.

Comment: you need to put this statement inside the if method

Comment: great :) glad could help  you